# Updating an object property that is inside an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update specfic property of an object inside an array of objects.

The collection:
[image: I want to update the ticket property inside the first object in the array.]

I want to update the ticket property inside the first object in the array.
This is what i've come up with:

`Flight.findOneAndUpdate({_id: "625764663bddec3da194ebc8"}, {$set: {"ecoSeats.$[0].ticket": "Hello"}});`

But nothing seems to be updated.

Comment: `{$set: {"ecoSeats.0.ticket": "Hello"}}`. Note that, this will only update the first element in the array.

Comment: I've tried it, does not work. @YongShun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Yong Shun 's answer is correct. I think your query is the problem, make sure you use `string`  or `ObjectId` in `_id`

`_id: "625764663bddec3da194ebc8"`  **!=**  `_id: ObjectId("625764663bddec3da194ebc8")`

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: ObjectId("625764663bddec3da194ebc8")
},
{
  $set: {
    "ecoSeats.0.ticket": "Hello"
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eSQrTiUwRqz)

Comment: I've tried both of your solutions guys, but unfortunately nothing seems to work :|

Comment: @FAHAD Check out my [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eSQrTiUwRqz), it works good. And don't just tell us that you fail. It would be better to give us testing data that you have tried. Or what kind of error message do you get. Tell me what's the different between your code with mine. Then we will tell you how to correct them.

Comment: Sorry if I caused any inconvenience, I've checked your mongoplayground but in my case it is wired that it does not work. Maybe because of the cloud? + I am not getting any errors. the only problem that the record won't update.

Comment: @FAHAD maybe show us a picture what you have tried on the cloud. You use `MongoDB Compass` or `Robo3T` or what to execute that command.

Comment: If you are using Node.JS MongoDB driver, you can work with a [callback](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate), check what is the result returned to see any document is queried, updated.

Comment: https://imgur.com/cCyq3Wu , you can see that it is not updating

Comment: found the problem, changing "multi" to multi fixed the problem for me, thank you so much for your time ;)